# How to get Auto Generated ID after Insert in Android RoomDB App

Tags: android, database, kotlin, android-room

I am building an Android application with MVVM Architecture.  Table A has an Auto-Generated Primary Key column which is a Foreign Key into Table B.  When the user clicks a button on the main fragment a row is inserted into Table A.  As part of this button's onClickListener, I'd like to retrieve the Auto-Generated Primary Key value (rowId) after creation and insert it into a column in Table B along with more data.

I am using MVVM Architecture, Coroutines, etc... but cannot figure out how to do this.  Below is some code and I'm happy to post more if anyone can help.

```
**// DAO Code**
@Dao
interface WLDAO {

@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
suspend fun insertTableA(tableAEntry: TableAEntry) : Long

**// Repo Code (function only)**
suspend fun insertTableA(tableAEntry: TableAEntry): Long {
    return WLDAO.insertTableA(TableAEntry)
}

**// View Model Code (function only)**
fun addToTableA(tableAEntry: TableAEntry) = viewModelScope.launch {
     repo.insertTableA(TableAEntry)     
}
```

Comment: The row ID is the `Long` returned by your Room DAO's `@Insert` function.

Comment: Apologies.... I wasn't very specific in the original post.  I am trying to get that Id back after issuing the Insert statement from the ViewModel in the Button's OnCLickListener handler.

Comment: The insert happens asynchronously. If your UI layer for some reason needs that ID, have your viewmodel emit it as part of some state. But "insert it into a column in Table B along with more data" sounds like it really should be handled by your repository, or perhaps your viewmodel.

Comment: I see... Thank you.  I think this is the hint I needed.  I see how I can do this through the ViewModel now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'd like to retrieve the Auto-Generated Primary Key value (rowId) after creation and insert it into a column in Table B along with more data.

The `Long` returned by your Room DAO's `@Insert` function is the row ID associated with that `INSERT` operation.

For using that value in further data operations, handle that in your repository or viewmodel. For example, your repository could have something like:

```kotlin
suspend fun doStuffWithBothTables(tableAEntry: TableAEntry, stuffForTableB: Whatever): Long {
    val rowID = WLDAO.insertTableA(TableAEntry)

    // TODO use rowID and stuffForTableB for some other DAO operations
}
```

Since `doStuffWithBothTables()` is itself a `suspend fun`, you can call other `suspend` functions normally, as if there were no threads or anything involved. So `doStuffWithBothTables()` can get the row ID from the first insert and then do additional work with that result.

Comment: This is fantastic!  I'm about 2 weeks into Android app development has this helped a ton!